# Saving Data: Check if value has changed?

Tags: php, html, database, forms, save

Lets say your form has a bunch of fields, and usually only 1 or 2 of them are changed and need to be saved.  Do you:

1. Just update the database with all values, regardless if they have changed.
2. Use form states, and only post back values that have changed.
3. Check the new value against the old value, externally to the class.
4. Check the new value against the old value, internally, in the `set_property()` method.
5. Then you'd have to keep an array of updated fields to be saved...

I might be wrong, but it seems most examples I've seen just do #1.  If you have a large list of 100+ posts in 1 table, you don't want to just loop through and save them all every time you update 1 field...

Comment: For the 100+ scenario that you mentioned, I think it might be advisable to use AJAX request/response rather than submitting the whole page over and over. That way you are only updating the values that need to be updated by sending requests only when you need to send them.

Comment: For example, I use that logic to implement tinymce autosave (saving information in the database at regular intervals as the user types them).

Comment: I would do something like option two, where you check if the data has been changed on the client-side. (JavaScript, onchange) Then when submitted, only data that has triggered `onchange` will be sent.

Comment: mySQL is smart and knows when an update command doesn't actually need to update the row http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186908/mysql-update-statement-overhead-for-same-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `#2`, keeping track of what has changed since last saved.