# database performance with updating forign key with the same value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

Is there any performance hit or locks on foreign key index acquired when updating a foreign key with the same value?

E.g.

```
update detail set master_id=x, property=y where id=z
```

master_id was previously x

does this query has the same performance and locks like

```
update detail set property=y where id=z
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql UPDATE statement - overhead for same values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186908/mysql-update-statement-overhead-for-same-values)

Comment: which storage engine?